# Wizard doesn't go to next step

Tags: primefaces, wizard

I have p:wizard inside a dialog. When I click on the next button, nothing happens. I've even put h:messages to catch any validation problems. But nothing appears. Here's my code:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="actionNewComplete" required="false"/>
        <cc:attribute name="update" required="false"/>
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <h:form prependId="false" id="formCreateOffre">
            <h:messages showDetail="true"/>
            <p:wizard id="wizardOffre" widgetVar="widgetWizardOffre" showNavBar="false" flowListener="#{offreController.handleFlow}">
                <p:tab id="tabOffre" title="Offre">
                    <p:panelGrid styleClass="ui-net-table">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOffreLabel_participant}" for="participant" />
                                <p:inputText styleClass="text" style="width: 50px;" id="participant" value="#{offreController.selected.participant}" title="#{bundle.CreateOffreTitle_participant}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateOffreLabel_rendezvous}" for="rendezvous" />
                                <p:calendar styleClass="text" id="rendezvous" value="#{offreController.selected.rendezvous}" disabled="#{offreController.selected.realisation eq null}" title="#{bundle.CreateOffreTitle_rendezvous}">
                                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="delais"/>
                                </p:calendar>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>                                             

                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="tabOffreClient" title="Client">
                    clients
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="tabOffreActivite" title="Activité">
                    activités
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="tabOffreService" title="Service">
                    services
                </p:tab>
            </p:wizard> 
            <p:commandButton value="Précédent" onclick="widgetWizardOffre.back();" icon="ui-icon-seek-prev"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Suivant" onclick="widgetWizardOffre.next();" icon="ui-icon-seek-next" iconPos="right"/>
        </h:form>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Here is the code of the bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "offreController")
@SessionScoped
public class OffreController extends AbstractController<Offre> {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{navigationController}")
    private NavigationController navigation;
    @EJB
    private app.tfe.netescape.business.OffreFacade ejbFacade;

    public OffreController() {
    }

    public String handleFlow(FlowEvent event) {
        return event.getNewStep();
    }
```

The flowListener method is called and returns the next step but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a getter and setter for every bean property you reference in your code. PrimeFaces will fail ungracefully on the wizard step in exactly this manner if it is unable to find both a getter and a setter - even for properties which you are only reading.

Addendum: also, the getters and setters should *only* do a get and a set of a local value. PrimeFaces doesn't handle other getters and setters well (I cannot explain why this doesn't work, but I've certainly observed it). If you have any additional logic, it should be processed in your listeners.

Answer (score 0):

what version of primefaces did you use?

If is version 5.1 change the event onclick:

onclick="widgetWizardOffre.next();"

by --->

onclick="PF('widgetWizardOffre').next();"

and use same for the event back: onclick="PF('widgetWizardOffre').back();"

Answer (score -1):

Your are already hiding the Navigation bar (next&back buttons), How can the navigation bar work then? Remove `showNavBar="false"`, it's true by default .